# Array literal in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

How do I write out an array literal in Hive?

```
SELECT PERCENTILE(my_column, [0.5, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.95]) AS quantiles
FROM my_table
```

Returns the error

```
FAILED: ParseException line xx:xx cannot recognize input near '[' '0.5' ',' in select expression
```

Comment: as per https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF , float is not supported

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `array` instead of `[]`

```
SELECT PERCENTILE(my_column, array(0.5, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.95)) AS quantiles
FROM my_table
```